# Snowflake: Recommendation how to integrate streaming data from Azure Event Hub

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to figure out how to best integrate streaming data from Azure Event Hub into Snowflake, e.g. with low latency and as cost-efficient as possible.

Brainstorming with myself I came up with 2 possibilities that both have some quite big disadvantages:

*Option 1: Setting up "Event Hub Capture" to export Event Hub data to blob storage and import to Snowflake*

This seems to be the most straightforward way. The data from Event Hub would be exported to Blob Storage automatically by enabling Event Hub Capture (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview). The genereated Avro files are then imported to Snowflake via Snowpipe (external tables, orchestration using Snowflake tasks).

Disadvantages:

- The minimum time window for export using Event Hub Capture is 1 minute. Snowflake tasks can also be scheduled to run every 1 minute. This means a potential max. delay of ca. 2 minutes (Event Hub -> Snowflake).
- A Snowflake warehouse would be running basically 24/7 (and this would produce quite large costs in Snowflake).

*Option 2: Creating an Azure Function that listens to Event Hub events and writes the data directly to Snowflake via Snowflake API*

Azure function would listen to Event Hub events and write the event data directly to Snowflake via Snowflake API (basically: send SQL INSERTs to DB via Snowflake API).

Advantages:

- No blob storage required
- "quite" low-latency

Disadvantages:

- As above: a Snowflake warehouse would be running 24/7 (costs)
- More development needed (Azure function)

Then I read the Snowflake documentation regarding streaming / Ingest SDK, so based on this:

*Option 3: Using Snowflake Streaming (?)*

Here I'm a bit confused, after reading the documentation. Disclaimer: I have no experience with Kafka or any other streaming technologies.

The Azure Event Hub documentation states:

> "Azure Event Hubs provides an Apache Kafka endpoint on an event hub,
> which enables users to connect to the event hub using the Kafka
> protocol."

Snowflake has a Snowflake Kafka connector. Can the Snowflake Kafka connector be used to connect to the Azure Event Hub to stream the data directly to Snowflake?

There is also a "Snowflake Ingest SDK API" aswell, available for Java. Unfortunately I don't know Java. :( Is there any way to use this with any other language, like Python?

I would be happy to get some feedback / best practices / real-life experience how to best implement streaming data from Azure Event Hub into Snowflake.

Comment: Can the Snowflake Kafka connector be used to stream from Azure Event Hub directly to Snowflake? Yes. Event Hub exposes a Kafka interface that the Snowflake connector can access. The connector also incorporates the ingest SDK API so you don't have to manage that.

Comment: See https://medium.com/snowflake/simplifying-real-time-data-ingestion-stream-azure-event-hubs-events-into-snowflake-with-snowpipe-62010d8f479a for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I have another thought in my mind: I want to refine your 3rd approach

If you want to achieve low latency then Kafka could be the best choice to handle real-time events as soon as a new row arrives. Once the data is setup in Kafka topic from Azure Event Hub.  Instead of JAVA/Python you can also try [Kafka Connector with Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-install#distributed-mode) with the [`Snowpipe Streaming Configuration`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-streaming-kafka) setting in Kafka Connector config file.

```
snowflake.ingestion.method: SNOWPIPE_STREAMING
```

In this approach, more effort is setting up the configuration. But it is only a one-time effort to setup your real-time streaming infra.

Please check the linked documentation of snowflake. This might give you a quick start.

Comment: A couple of thoughts... 1) if you have no previous Kafka experience then it would be a pretty steep learning curve plus costs etc. for implementation 2) If you want to effectively continuously load data into Snowflake then (under most/all solutions) you're going to be incurring Snowflake costs (either warehouse or serverless) - so I don't think that's a con for any particular solution, it's just a cost for what you want to do

Comment: Yes you are right, But I believe while designing the data-intensive system we have to consider a lot of metrics and priorities which we can't accept e.g. here in this case ~2 mins is considered as high latency and on the other side what we can accept or compromise e.g. cost (or not) etc. Learning new tools is always challenging in the beginning but it will pay off the cost at the end.  This is like a trade-off in order to achieve something you need to forego something. 
But still these are my thoughts.